# disable auto scrolling when select out div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

im crazy with this trouble, i try to make a scrolling with angularjs and jquery, here a litle code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gxz27ae/) in my machine this run idk why dont run in jsfiddle, well my problem is when i making click and mousemove, i can scrolling, but when the mouse is out `<div id="move2"....`, the scroll move very fast, is like if you put click in list and drag it to down, the scrolling move very fast to down.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

If any have the same problem, only put .

```
style="overflow:hidden;height:300 px"
```

then the only method for scrolling is the one you created with AngularJS (ng-mousedown, ng-mouseleave ... etc)